# Enter the natural number n and print even smaller numbers n and odd numbers smaller than n

Tags: c

Thank you all
I want to the program code" Enter the natural number n and print the even number smaller than n and the odd number is smaller than n ". When I am trying to use the for () loop it does not run properly. And I do not understand why so. This is my code

```
puts("even number");
for(i=0;i<=n;i=i+2)
    {printf("%3d",i);}
printf("\n");
puts("odd number ");
for(j=1;j<=n;j=j+2);
    {printf("%3d",i);}
```

And this is the result when I give n = 10
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3PJW.png)
Thanks all

Comment: Where is `n` defined ? did you use `scanf` ?

Comment: Sorry for typos .i will fix it

Comment: Why have you changed the question? What ***is*** your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second loop should be

```
for(j=1;j<=n;j=j+2)         // remove the final ;
    { printf("%3d",j); }    // change i to j
```

The supposed body of the `j` loop was not in the loop at all, so was executed once, printing the final value of `i`.

Comment: Thank you very much .I will fix it